# Where should I store api key in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, app-config, api-key

What is the best practice for storing/retrieving API keys in rails3?

Should I create my own application yaml and access it through there?  If so, how?

Sorry for the noob question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the [settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) plugin for things like this.  Very easy to use.

Add settingslogic to your `Gemfile` and `bundle install`:

```
gem 'settingslogic'
```

Create a directory for your settings and place the settingslogic yaml in there:

```
/my_app/config/settings/my_settings.yml
```

You can include default settings and per environment settings.  The file looks like this:

```
defaults: &defaults
  api_key: abc123

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Add this file: `app/models/my_settings.rb`, start up your app and you are good to go

```
class MySettings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/settings/my_settings.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

Now you can use call these settings from anywhere in the app like so:

```
MySettings.api_key
```

Comment: I decided to create a gem similar to settingslogic, but without the need to add MySettings class.  More info here:  http://www.cowboycoded.com/2011/04/08/application-wide-variables-for-your-rails-3-app-using-yettings/

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'll probably use it with my next project.